# Redirect to new domain preserving URL address

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a parked domain on top of my main domain. 
I need to redirect `myolddomain.com/some-page` to `mynewdomain.com/some-page`

I have tried some .htaccess changes but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to point both domains in to the same server and the same document root, thus both `myolddomain.com` and `mynewdomain.com` gets served by the same thing. But if that's not possible, you can use mod_rewrite or mod_proxy to proxy the request from the old domain to the new domain without changing the address in a browser's URL address bar. The mod_proxy directives *must* be in the vhost or server config:

Using proxypass:

```
ProxyPass /some-page http://mynewdomain.com/some-page
```

or if you can use regex, for example:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://mynewdomain.com/$1
```

But if you want this in an htaccess file, you can use mod_rewrite's `P` flag to send the request off to mod_proxy (note that mod_proxy **must still be loaded**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myolddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^some-page$ http://mynewdomain.com/some-page [L,P]
```

likewise, you can use regex pattern in the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} myolddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mynewdomain.com/$1 [L,P]
```